# Can I Pass Command Line Arguments To Start Without Debugging

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, I know how to pass command line arguments through the Debug Tab in the Properties page of the project, but I wonder if it is possible to pass such arguments to the app when I launch  it through "Start Without Debugging" ?

I Googled over this topic but on one is pointing to that, it seems VS does not allow us to do it. Beside that, I also wonder if VS has some log file that shows which command the VS has run to launch the application ?

Comment: They should be passed regardless of the launch mode. If you run w/o debugging (but still in Debug mode) it's only that the debugger is not attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With or without debugging, the commandline arguments specified in the debugging form are passed to `c#` programs. You can do something like the following to replace the arguments from within the program for testing:

```cs
    if ((args.Length == 1) && (args[0] == "test"))
    {
        args = new string[]
        {
            "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"
        };
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(", ", args)}");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Your answer actually contains 2 answers. I would upvote the first sentence and will not really accept the second part as an answer (more just a as sidenote only). It's quite confusing.